# Field Extension Question, Is my Proof Correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose $F$ is a field extension of $K$, $E$ is an intermediate field between $K$ and $F$, and $u$ is in $F$ and algebraic over $K$.  Prove that if $[K(u)：K]$ and $[E：K]$ are relatively prime, then one has $[E(u):E]=[K(u):K]$.

Proof:

Now, $[E(u):E][E:K]=[E(u):K(u)][K(u):K]=[E(u):K]$. And so if $[E:K]=m$, and $[K(u):K]=n$, where $(n,m)=1$, then $mn \mid [E(u):K]$ which implies that $[E(u):K]\geq mn$.  Now $E(u)$ is the smallest field that contains both $E$ and $K(u)$.  And so, $[E(u):K]\leq [E:K][K(u):K]$, which implies that $[E(u):K]\leq mn$, and so, $[E(u):K]=mn$.  And so, $[E(u):E]=n=[K(u):K]$.  QED.

Notice that I didn't use the fact the $u$ is algebraic over $K$.  Thanks!

Comment: *Notice that I didn't use the fact that $u$ is algebraic over $K$.* Sure you did. You did it as soon as you said "$[K(u):K]=n$".  It also looks like all the other extensions are meant to be finite degree, hence algebraic, as well.

Comment: implicit in the problem, they tell you that $[K(u):K]=n$, by stating relative primeness.

Comment: Either way, you can't very well say "I didn't use the fact" as if the problem were independent of the fact. It very much depends on the fact since, as you said, *it is implicit in the problem* and you can't even state it without assuming so.

Answer (score 1):

You *did* use that $u$ is algebraic over $K$, because this guarantees that $[K(u):K]$ is finite.

You are also *given* that $E$ is a finite extension of $K$, so also $E(u)$ is a finite extension of $K$. Hence
$$
[E(u):K]=[E(u):E][E:K]=[E(u):K(u)][K(u):K]
$$
Your assumption is that $[E:K]=m$ and $[K(u):K]=n$ are coprime. You conclude correctly that $[E(u):K]$ is a common multiple of $m$ and $n$, so that it is a multiple of $mn$.

How you got the converse inequality is unclear.

The fact to use is that $u$ satisfies a polynomial with coefficients in $K$ of degree $[K(u):K]=n$, so its minimal polynomial over $E$ has degree at most $n$. Hence $[E(u):E]\le n$ and therefore
$$
[E(u):K]=[E(u):E][E:K]\le mn
$$

Comment: The converse inequality is actually a well-known inequality in Dummit and Foote.  It is implicit in the question that [K(u):K] is finite, so no need to for knowing that u is algebraic.

Comment: @mover002 That should be quoted.

Comment: Proposition 21, page 529: Dummit and Foote

Comment: @mover002 As you see, you don't need that, but it probably is proved in the same way.